# Problem with variable argument function in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create a variable length function (obviously, heh) in C++, and what I have right now works, but only for the first argument. If someone could please let me know how to get this working with all the arguments that are passed, I would really appreciate it.

Code:

```
void udStaticObject::accept( udObjectVisitor *visitor, ... )
{
    va_list marker;
    udObjectVisitor *i = visitor;
    va_start( marker, visitor );
    while( 1 )
    {
        i->visit_staticObject( this );
//the if here will always go to the break immediately, allowing only 
//one argument to be used
        if( ( i = va_arg( marker, udObjectVisitor* ) ) )
            break;
    }
    va_end( marker );
}
```

Based on my past posts, and any help posts I make in general, there is probably some information that I did not provide that you will need to know to help. I apologize in advance if I forgot anything, and please let me know what you need to know so I can provide the information.

Comment: How do you know how many arguments there are?  Is there a null pointer required to be at the end of the arguments list?

Comment: I don't know how many arguments there are and that is the problem I was trying to figure out, eventually finding the if( ( i =... ) ) solution that someone put somewhere. I thought it worked until I tried three arguments. A null pointer would be a good idea though...

Comment: @Freezerburn:  Really, the best option, since this is C++, is probably to take a vector of objects to visit and iterate over the elements in the vector.  I wouldn't use a variadic function for this (or for just about anything else, for that matter).

Comment: @Jamen McNellis: I suppose that is true, I was hoping that I could use the slightly more elegant-looking solution of a variable argument function (at least to my eyes). Are variadic functions really that bad though? I changed some code before your last comment and managed to get it working by using a null pointer as the last argument. I just don't understand why a vector is much more desirable than my current solution.

Comment: Var-arg functions allow to pass the user anything in by accident, you lose the static typing which is one of the strong sides of C++. The language doesn't give you a way to figure out the arg count, you need to pass either an additional parameter containing the arg count or use a sentinel value - again, both error-prone. A vector of visitor pointers avoids those error-sources and has the benefit of self-documentation.

Comment: (I moved my comments to an answer so I had more room to expand on my explanation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a variadic function, you need some way to tell the function how many arguments were passed.  For example, `printf()` and friends take a formatting string that contains format specifiers for each of the passed arguments, and they count the number of format specifiers to determine how many arguments were passed.

When passing a list of pointers, you can accomplish this "more simply" by passing a null pointer as the last argument.  That way, you simply read arguments until you reach the null pointer.

**However**, you should seriously consider **not** using a variadic function for this.  You can accomplish the same behavior by taking a vector of pointers as a parameter and iterating over the contents of that vector.  There are a number of reasons why this is superior to using a variadic function:

- Variadic functions have absolutely no type safety.  You lose any and all type information about the arguments when you pass them to a variadic function, so for example, a caller of your function could pass a numeric value instead of a pointer and you'd never be able to tell inside of your function.
- With the variadic solution, the caller must correctly indicate the number of arguments.  If the caller omits the null pointer at the end (or otherwise misinforms your function of how many arguments there are) and you try to read more arguments than were passed, you end up with undefined behavior.  Right now you might say "well, that's not hard to forget," but inevitably, someone will forget or screw it up and debugging this sort of issue is a beating.
- The solution taking a vector and iterating over its contents is far simpler to implement, easier to debug, and much more idiomatic in C++.

Wherever there is an option between using a variadic function and not using a variadic function, you should prefer not to use a variadic function (I'll admit, I have never written a variadic function in any of the C++ code I have written, though I've written a few in C).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the test is backwards? Try this:

```
    if( ( i = va_arg( marker, udObjectVisitor* ) ) != NULL )
        break;
```